# Create a standalone photo album

Tags: ios, photos

I have one series of photos that I show to people I meet often. Using the iOS Photos app with an album is fine, except that it takes a while to launch and then find the right album, and sometimes that app is slow.

What I'd like is to have an app (or an export process, or *something*) which allows me to select some photos maybe the first time I launch it, and then just displays those photos, and only those photos, when I start it up. I'd just like them to fill the screen and I could swipe between them.

Then, I could just pop open my phone, launch that app, and be showing the photos immediately.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create an iCloud Shared Album and give it a web URL, then "bookmark" that URL with a home screen icon.

1. Open the Photos app and tap on the Shared tab.
2. If you don't see the + icon at the upper-left, tap "< Sharing" there. Tap the + icon.
3. Give your album a name and tap Next. Optionally, share it with contact(s). Tap Create.
4. Tap on the album you just created. Add photos by tapping on + in the grey square.
5. Tap on the People tab. Turn on Public Website. You'll be provided a URL.
6. Tap Share Link and then tap Copy.
7. Open Safari and paste the URL into the address bar. Tap the Share icon at the bottom and tap Add to Home Screen.

Anytime you want to share the photos in this album with people, just tap on the icon on your home screen.

Comment: Well done @tubedogg. The only downside is that I can't view it if I'm offline.

Comment: Hm. Also it's a bit difficult to control the order.